# How to dynamically reset contentEl?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

What is the best way to dynamically change `contentEl`? I can see `update` method, but it works with string/template input, and I can still use it to reset content using somehow innerHTML. But what about resetting DOM element itself?

```
var divA = document.createElement("div");
divA.innerHTML = "divA";
var divB = document.createElement("div");
divB.innerHTML = "divB";
var win  = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'An Example',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    contentEl: divA
}).show();

window.setTimeout(function() {
    //this will work, but what about DOM?
    var buf = document.createElement('div');
    buf.appendChild(divB);
    win.update(buf.innerHTML);
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a current example or code you can share?

Comment: @Jackson - provided, but do not understand how it actually can help you to answer )

Comment: I'd say i'm just more of a visual (or perhaps lazy) learner. Looks like `Efran Cobisi` beat me to it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [replaceWith() method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-replaceWith), along with the config object for the new element to create:

```
Ext.get(contentEl).replaceWith({ html: '<div>hello, world</div>' });
```

Comment: can you, please, provide a snippet of code. Does not work for me even after calling doLayout()

Comment: @Efran, it won't work. `replace` doesn't take template as a parameter. It takes as parameter `The id of the node, a DOM Node or an existing Element`.

Comment: @Molecule: my error, I've referenced the wrong method. The correct one is replaceWith() - post updated and new snippet added... Thanks.

Comment: @Efran Cobisi, sorry for being so strict, but it is not for me, it is for community. See, I cannot mark your answer as accepted as long as I can not reproduce your steps. There is a code above, in the question. Can you show me how exactly you suppose to make it work.